# Set document library Document Template using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, document-template

I'm using the code below to create document libraries, but I need to set the "Document template" value to "Web part page". I can list the document templates using $spWeb.DocTemplates - but how can I set the value using PowerShell?

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb -Identity <url>
$listTemplate = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListTemplateType]::DocumentLibrary
$spWeb.Lists.Add("Listname","List description", $listTemplate)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my answer here: [Set the Document Template of a Document Library programmatically](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18977/set-the-document-template-of-a-document-library-programmatically/19002#19002)

I think you can easily convert code provided there to PowerShell (if not let me know). Also be sure to read additional info.