# Where is Forms folder in sharepoint document library?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have seen in an article that document template is stored in the Forms folder of the library.Where is the physical path of Forms Library?or in content database?

I have created a document template through following code

```
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                SPDocumentLibrary lib = (SPDocumentLibrary)web.Lists["DocumentLibraryInstance"];
                string urlStr = @"Lists/DocumentLibraryInstance/Forms/anish.doc";
                lib.DocumentTemplateUrl = urlStr;
                lib.Update();
```

Is the file extension correct?

Comment: Maybe your list "DocumentLibraryInstance" is not a document library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the answer given here

[Set the Document Template of a Document Library programmatically](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18977/set-the-document-template-of-a-document-library-programmatically/19002#19002)

http://blog.quercussolutions.com/index.php/using-a-custom-template-for-a-document-library/

For word Document template extension will be .dotx

Comment: The two links gave me good idea about document templates.But i am getting an error "new document requires a microsoft sharepoint foundation-compatible" when click the ribbon item new document.

Comment: Check with 1.Compatible Browser Version 2. Element 2: Compatible Office Version 3. Element 3: Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Support in Office. refer this one: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/440704/Document-Library-Enable-New-Document-Edit-Document

Comment: I am using office 2007

Comment: Try to install and configure Office Web Applications on the server, You will get support fix info here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/833714